# boot repair not working do not have windows 10 disc

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am using linux **but I bought this computer with windows 10 and there is no disc and I am not ready to go and buy another one**
so I asked my sister to make a bootable USB I told her I already had a program for it that would help with getting all the drivers I needed before I installed debian. I was lucky I am not a first time linux user, as I go to set it up later that day in my local y, I get driver errors. I thought it was nothing so I ignored it. I continue setting debian up in the car ride home and I can not complete it.
I get home and turn on my computer, but to my surprise and horror, its going right to grub. I dont have internet, Ethernet wasnt working, I go to sleep and finally boot with my linux disc.

I can not access my windows data and I am getting annoyed with this. I keep getting the error **GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.**

I did that and it still wont work. is there a way this can be fixed.

Comment: Quick Google search and I found you can download the Windows 10 for free from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE] or more generally [SU].

Answer (score 1):

The "Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" message indicates that you've booted your Linux installation medium in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, not in the firmware's native EFI/UEFI mode. If you're using the original manufacturer's Windows 10 installation, it's almost certainly in EFI/UEFI mode, so doing a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation of your OS would be a mistake. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for information on why this is so, and tips on how to avoid falling into this trap.

As to Windows, it's probably still bootable if you use your computer's built-in boot manager. Unfortunately, the details of how to access this tool vary from one computer to another. It's usually done by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key early in the boot process, but which key to use is not standardized. You should also be able to boot Windows once you successfully install a Linux distribution and its GRUB; GRUB will enable you to chainload to the Windows boot loader. If you need to boot Windows before you can get Linux up and running, try my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on CD-R or USB flash drive (download links for both are provided on that site). Once rEFInd boots, it scans for boot loaders and enables you to launch anything that it finds.